# How to disable some element reaction to any mouse event without interrupting underlaying element events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I'm trying to make a simple pop-up `<div>` that's designed to show mouse coordinates while a user is dragging a mouse pointer. This pop-up appears at the bottom on the right to the mouse pointer. The *underlaying* `div` has its own very important mouse event handlers (e.g. `.mousemove()`). The pop-up `div` is quite far away from the mouse pointer (about 16 pixels downwards and 16 pixels to the right). Let's say, a user is resizing some object, and that pop-up is displaying a new size of that object. This is o.k. if the user is resizing the object slowly. But as soon as the user abruptly resizes the object and points the pop-up `div`, the underlaying `div` loses focus, and its event handler, that's responsible for resizing, gets "broken" (it's like the mouse pointer "forgets" the underlying `div`) because it's not designed to cooperate with overlaying `div`-s at all.

Is there any ability to suppress any pop-up `div` mouse events allowing the underlaying `div` events go *strictly continuously*?

I tried something like that:

```
var BLACK_HOLE = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;       
};
$popUp
    .click(BLACK_HOLE)
    .dblclick(BLACK_HOLE)
    .focusin(BLACK_HOLE)
    .focusout(BLACK_HOLE)
    .hover(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mousedown(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mouseenter(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mouseleave(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mousemove(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mouseout(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mouseover(BLACK_HOLE)
    .mouseup(BLACK_HOLE);
```

It doesn't work the way I need. Did anyone get the same issue? Is it possible to bypass it? Perhaps, there's a complete jQuery plugin for that... Confused...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: upd: 10 days later, the question has been launched to the black hole for real. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper event bubbling/capturing is the solution and the salvation. The bug is fixed in my application.